# Debug OpenCL installation issues and beignet

Tags: opencllink

I am trying to make Mathematica recognize my OpenCL installation, which is [beignet](http://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/Beignet/). It is experimental software, so I know that it probably won't work (even `clinfo` terminates with an error after displaying some info), yet I would like to know exactly why `OpenCLQ[]` returns `False`.

Comment: Does `Trace` or `TracePrint` help?

Comment: I think it would probably help to look at the source code for the OpenCLLink package (``$InstallationDirectory`SystemFiles`Links`OpenCLLink``) and follow the logic through. I had trouble with OpenCL in the past and did so myself; there seemed to be quite a few strange assumptions/incorrect logic involved in it, at least in version 8. This may have been improved but I have the feeling it would still not be completely robust. Anyway, this should give you an idea of what is needed for `OpenCLQ[]` to return `True`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it's a load of text, not really readable

Comment: @OleksandrR. I can't find the logic in the .m files, or am I looking i nthe wrong place? I fear that the logic is in the binaries

Comment: Sorry, yes, the layout of these packages seems to have changed (or I misremembered). The logic behind `PlatformCount` (on which I suppose you saw that `OpenCLQ` depends) is in ``$InstallationDirectory`SystemFiles`Links`GPUTools`WGLPrivate.m``.